# FileSystemView get war file icon null pointer

Tags: java, file-handling

I am using `javax.swing.chooser.FileSystemView` to get system file icons and display them for uploaded files in my web application.

It is all working well for various file types, however when I am trying to upload a `.war` file, Java is returning a `Null Pointer Exception`. How can I know if this particular file type is supported or not by this method?

Anyone had a similar issue?

This is the code I am using

```
// gets a 16x16 size image icon for list view 
Icon smallIcon = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(file);
Image smallImage = ((ImageIcon) smallIcon).getImage();
```

I am running this code on a `Windows 7` machine if it makes any difference.

Thanks for your help :)

**Edit**: Turns out this problem wasn't the icon. I have this line of code

```
String contentType = getServletContext().getMimeType(file.getName());
```

which accepts the file I uploaded as a parameter and checks the type of file. I am doing this to check if the file is an image or not. For the case of a war file it is returning null for some reason

Comment: When `smallIcon` is null, give a self-defined default image.

Comment: i just tried it with a `.war` file and it didn't throw an exception. perhaps you made some change to previous code to cause `file` to be null.